# OpenCV- False Detection

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.5, haar-classifier

I'm a 1st-grade cs student and I know only a little bit of python. For a project, I need to use OpenCV to detect several traffic signs. I searched a little bit on the web and I decided to use Haar-Cascade classifier. I followed this tutorial : [haar-cascade](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/)

I trained the code for this sign [left-sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxNlg.png)
Everything was fine up to this point. However my code (trained with 3000 positive 1500 negative jpgs and finished 8 stages)detects both right and left signs. Code needs to recognize right and left signs separately because my aim is to command my robot to turn left or turn right.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

ok_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('new_kocum.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    oks = ok_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in oks:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(img,'ok',(x-w,y-h), font, 0.5, (11,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the right sign : [right-sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdqBD.png)

So my question: Is it possible to fix that just by changing the code? If easier, which method should I use to detect these signs?

Comment: Haar-Cascades are amazingly inacurate...

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct way: you need add to the negative set a lot of the right signs.
2. The best way: don't use haar-cascade.
3. Simplest way: train the second classifier (for example naive Bayes) for comparing left and right signs after work you cascade. Features: correlation between images, Hu-moments etc.